# Why method overloading with boxing & widening giving ambiguous error?

Tags: java, wrapper, overloading

```
public class Aman {
    void m(Byte b, Integer i) {     // autoboxing, autoboxing

    }
    void m(Number n, int i) {       // autoboxing -> widening, no conversion

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte b = 23;
        Aman obj = new Aman();
        obj.m(b, 24);
    }
}
```

I have read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2 document but can

someone please explain step by step why the method invocation is giving ambiguous error, through the

steps described in this document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no applicable method signature that doesn't use boxing/unboxing, so the compiler looks for all signatures that are applicable with boxing [(spec ref)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). It finds that both methods are applicable.

Then, it checks if one is more specific than the other. This requires each parameter type of one method to be a subtype of the corresponding parameter type of the other method. Since [`int` and `Integer` are not comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), the call is ambiguous.

The reason that calls to m(Integer) and m(int) are normally not ambiguous is that the appropriate method is found in "phase one" in the linked spec, before boxing is even considered. Here, you could resolve the ambiguity by changing the call to:

```
obj.m(Byte.valueOf(b), 24);
```

Comment: I think first method is more specific then second one because all values that can pass first method can also pass second one. From the document : **one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.**

Comment: The rule for more-specific is that all the parameter types of one method are subtypes of the corresponding parameter types of the other, not that all possible values passed to one can pass to the other. `Integer` is not a subtype of `int`, but neither is `int` a subtype of `Integer`.

Comment: but if we talk of primitive values then, it is not about subtypes but which values can be passed.
Moreover why obj.m(Byte.valueOf(b), 24) calls m(Number n, int i) method ?

Comment: No, primitive values still have subtype relations -- see the spec I linked in my answer. And that method is chosen because it can be called without autoboxing, so the other method is never even considered as a match.

Comment: Thank you @Russell Zahniser i read and understood it completely but just another doubt that in which phase is widening checked ?

Comment: All the phases allow widening conversion; the second phase just *also* allows boxing/unboxing conversion.

Comment: then where the order of priority widening > boxing > varargs come into play

Comment: It's all in that spec section: The compiler tries widening first (phase 1), then widening plus boxing if that fails (phase 2), then all three if that fails (phase 3).

Comment: thnks @Russell Zahniser for your patience and time and answering so well

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you [linked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without
>   permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity
>   method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase
>   then processing continues to the second phase.

Nothing happens here because none of the methods match `(byte, int)` without boxing one of the arguments.

> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while
>   allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable
>   arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this
>   phase then processing continues to the third phase.

In this step, both methods match if you do some boxing on the arguments. If you box `byte`, the arguments match

```
void m(Number n, int i) {
```

if you box the `byte` and the `int`, the argument match

```
void m(Byte b, Integer i) {
```

So several methods are applicable.

> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the
>   three phases of applicability testing, then the most specific one is
>   chosen, as specified in section [§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

If you go through all those rules, you'll find there is no more specific method, so the call is ambiguous.

Comment: how can you say that no method is more applicable ?

Comment: @user3519914 Following the rules in [§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), none is more specific than the other.